# Problems with std::set<string> insert function

Tags: c++

I wrote a small program to insert a set of strings into std::set.

For this I have defined a set variable in a .h file and then in my main function I am just doing inert in to the set defined in .h file.

I am getting core dump and here is the stack trace of the same

```
#0  0x007a14a1 in std::string::compare () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x080d459c in std::operator< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >    (__lhs=@0xbfef09d0, __rhs=@0x87de230) at /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat- linux/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2158
#2  0x080d4580 in std::less<std::string>::operator() (this=0xb65d530, __x=@0xbfef09d0, __y=@0x87de230) at /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/stl_function.h:227
#3  0x0810411a in std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::string, std::_Identity<std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> >::insert_unique (this=0xb65d530, __v=@0xbfef09d0) at /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/stl_tree.h:919
#4  0x0810246c in std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> >::insert (this=0xb65d530, __x=@0xbfef09d0) at /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/stl_set.h:314
```

Sample code:

```
X.h

    std::set<string> test;

X.C

    int main()
    {
        test.insert("hi");
        return 0;
    }
```

Can some one please let me know the mistake I am doing?

Comment: Are you including `<string>` and `<set>` in the relevant places? It would be better if you could post a small code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: It works [fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5bd4c5e3e53a9db32807c3cb8f96f2ac-542192d2d8aca3c820c7acc656fa0c68). Did you name the source file with `.c` extension ?

Comment: Yes I am including <string> and <set>.

Comment: Is the `std::set<string>` line a typo? it should be `std::set<std::string>`. This sample code is too simplistic to tell us anything, is this all you have?